# jSignature fails with missing import plugin

Tags: jsignature

Calling jSignature with

```
var hiddenSignature = $('#signature' + i).jSignature();
hiddenSignature.jSignature('setData', 'base30' + signatureContentBase30);
```

gives this error

```
jSignature.min.js:57 Uncaught Error: jSignature is unable to find import plugin with for format 'undefined'
    at r.fn.init.f (jSignature.min.js:57)
    at r.fn.init.$.fn.(formso365.nintex.com/Pages/anonymous function) [as jSignature] (https://progressivehomecare.sharepoint.com/sites/intakeworkflow-dev/SiteAssets/ScriptLibraries/jSignature.min.js:61:18)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (registerSignatureFields.js:49)
    at Function.each (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4)
    at init.each (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (registerSignatureFields.js:23)
    at c (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4)
    at Object.add [as done] (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4)
    at init.ready (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4)
    at registerSignatureFields.js:14
```

Using this code

```
var hiddenSignature = $('#signature' + i).jSignature();
hiddenSignature.jSignature('setData', 'data:image/jsignature;base30,' + signatureContentBase30);
```

I get the error

```
jSignature.min.js:65 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at v (jSignature.min.js:65)
    at u (jSignature.min.js:65)
    at HTMLCanvasElement.r (jSignature.min.js:66)
    at r.fn.init.f (jSignature.min.js:57)
    at r.fn.init.$.fn.(formso365.nintex.com/Pages/anonymous function) [as jSignature] (https://progressivehomecare.sharepoint.com/sites/intakeworkflow-dev/SiteAssets/ScriptLibraries/jSignature.min.js:61:18)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (registerSignatureFields.js:49)
    at Function.each (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4)
    at init.each (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (registerSignatureFields.js:23)
    at c (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4)
```

I don't know what to try and this is my first time with jSignature (taking over from someone else)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about http://www.unbolt.net/jSignature/

Use

```
$('#signature').jSignature('getData', 'default')
```

This will create something like:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABm0AAAGbCAYAAAAm8dSlAAAc1klEQVR4nO3deZRtZ1kn4B8CzZBb+92VBFFAEZHGKEIrKKKAQQQFmZLa766EQaBFFrYgouIsYqMyrkahlcg8CCJTmCQhYQ4kkoQhA2EIECCEIRAyz7lJ/3F2ILAWiMuWQ+59nrXeddY9VbXP+51bVX/sX73flwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADfVfqaqa3bpfqxGfsdqfkR6+4IAAAAAABgF9XXzEbfMsP8wIzzM1L91lR/ItXnpfqKVF+e6jNTfUrG+THr7hYAAAAAgP8vHnLd7OgbpPpm2dy6dYb5lzNuPzQ1/0nG/tsM/dJUH5PqD2boIzL0kan+t+W596em41LzCRn6pNT80VSfnOpPpvrTqf5shv78N9TnvlbzaRl6VdWf/VpNp36t+tOp/tRyzY8v1/9Yhv5IhunDGfpDqfmEVB+f6g+m+gOrvvrYVY/TMak+OtX/lmE+alV9ZIbpPRn63cuajsjQ70r1O1bXmY5PTW9X/15dHd+rK3vuty1ByFtS8+GpPjzVh6WmN6f60FQfkqHflKHfmGF6Q4Z+XWo+ONWvTvWrUvMrUvO/pPrlq8f5Favnp1en+jWp+eAM/boM/foM/YbVdfpNqT5kuf5hy+u+Zenlg8v396lXCWZ2pvrijP25VL83w/yibPYjs2N7n3X/1gAAAAAA4Jva91rZ48AbZsf2PtnsO2bs+2ScHpqa/3D5K/1XpfqdGfrEJRg5OzVdtPy1/s5UX5rqy5Z/X5bq81N9Rqo/k+qTUv2R1U3l+fBUH7q6mT29IUO/dnWDul+Z6pdn6JdmmF+SYXphanpeanpOaj4oNR20epwPSvU/fn1Nz75KPWf5mqX6uanpeRn6BRmmF2XoF2eY/2kVJE3/vNwwf8Xq9Zeb5UO/dnWjfHrD190sH/qQr90wn968umneh1/lxvlbl5vnV8MgYt0ByLr7+I/23Men+h0Z+l1XCe3evQR5R2aYj1qCyaOzCv2OXYLAD6Sm41J9QoY+MUOf9NXgcPWz9U3Cw28MDr8aGq5eu+Z3pqbjMvS/ZZyfkc3+zVTfNhv77bXu3ywAAAAAACRJ9r1W9tz/Jqm+bYb5nhmnh2bov1wFIn14qo/POH1uCVguT/WFqT431ecsf6l/8RLInLMENSek+u2pfnnG+emp6Q8yTA9ITXfN5tats/cBN0r6v6171QAAAAAAAN85exx4wwwH3D7j/OCM0xMyTi9ZpjxOSvUXlwDm8gx9UaovSPVFSwBzUaq/tGwRdmSqX5Oxn5ma/iDj9NBszvfORt8hQ/9IxvuN614mAAAAAADA+uzVN85G32cVxvQRqf7wch7LGUvocvlV6qLl+U+m+ugM0xtS07NS/Uep3jYFAwAAAAAA8M2M+98047Rvxn5IhunvljNRTk5N51zljJhLUn36crD4UanpoFUQs7WVHf1jpmAAAAAAAAD+XQ+5bvbc+vGM030z9u+mpmdl7Pdk7M8tgcz5y9kxl6X6zOXg8Vel+k9T/YvZOHDvda8AAAAAAADg6mO835ixfyE1PyLD/PRUH5ahT1vCmC+n+vPL1mVXpPozqT48NT05Qz8otXW73KB3rHsJAAAAAAAAVz/jfOfU9McZ+o2p/myGvmiZnjl1CWcuztgfSk0vyzD/eWrqbG7fKtn3WutuHQAAAAAA4Opv7Mdl6EuWbc3OW+oDqfn5qX5sNud7Z+gfWXebAAAAAAAAu7ZhOiDVF6f6glRfkaE/lJqfk+rfzLB1++Th1153iwAAAAAAALuPzfneqX5uhv58av5Sqj+W6k8vZ9a8T5ADAAAAAADwnbZje59UPzxjvzg1fWoJcY5L9bGpPlmQAwAAAAAAsA7j/jdN9ZSan5zqt6X63FR/aglxjhbkAAAAAAAArMvm9q0yzA9MzU9L9VtS/aUM/cWM/aFUH7+EOlek+oOCHAAAAAAAgO+k8YAfysZ0r9T0BxnmF6X62Ax9Uaq/nOpTU336EuR8PDW/IsP8W4IcAAAAAACA75Rh6xYZ5ntmmH87Nf99qo+8SoBzyfJ4ZqpPSfUxqX5Van5+hun/ZJj+IsP0qAzTAzLMv5xxvnOG/pmM27fJRt8y4/43zR4H3jDj/cbkIddd91IBAAAAAACujq6RPQ/4gezY/86p+U8y9BEZ+4RUH7eck/PZZUrn3KuEO5em+qJUX5Dq85e6YHnu0qsEQecvQdAXU9OpqT45Q5+4TP8ckerDMvRrU/M/p/q5GfuZqempGecnZJj+LDX/foZ+ZGr+jQz9oNTU2ZzvnZruLjgCAAAAAAAY7zem+map7Z9KTXdN9ZSaHpbqx6bmv0nNf59hemGqX5mh/zXVb0v1URn7A6n+cKo/mXH63BIGnZNhuijVO1O9c7WV23R+xj53CYrO+SZ1bqrPu0pgdGGqL15Co51LcLRzCY8uXD737FR/ZZkw+vwSJJ2S6o9l6JOWoOrYpdcTU9Pxqent37r6bV9f09tT8zsz9BEZpvdkmI9K9XtT0zGp+X2p/kBqOi41n5ChP5ShP5yhP5Lqjy0h2cdT0ydS/cnUfEqqP53qzyy9fjZDn5ZhPm313HzKss3dR1f9zycs5xe9L9VHZ5iPytDvXtb13lT/Q6ofm3G6bza2fjQ7+gZJrrHubycAAAAAAOC7zsOvnb3vs5GNA/fOHv192atvnHH/m6a2fjjD1i2yY3ufbG7fKuP2bVJ92wz9M9noO2Sz75hx2ncVIE13zzDfczWRs90Zt38t1Q/PsP2oVWAx/1nG+QmpfkqG+Rmp/seM/YJUv3QJmV6X6kNW4Ucfn+q3L/WOb17zO79W/Y4lwHlLqg9L9aEZ+k0Z+o0Z+vWryaJ+zbL93CtS/fLU9LIM/dIM8z9lmF+SoV+cYXrRKvian5+anpfq56bm56SmZy/1vAzTCzPML0lNL0vN/7Jc8+DV68z/mupDU/Phq6CoT14CqjOXIOvyVF+2hFurM4/G/lCq35Sh/zYb/esZ5ztn3P+mEewAAAAAAAD8F7lJXy8bfctU3y1DP3o55+jNyyTUGUugc8kyvXTFMqX0sVQfvtrGbvthGbdvkxv0jnUvBQAAAAAAYNe2R39fhv6Z1Dynpr9O9atT/f7V1nJ90TKtc3mGvihDf2E10TMfnJqflGE+MLV983UvAQAAAAAAYNd35bTO0PdP9VMy9uuWbeU+v5wjdPlSFyzPfTTj9J7U9NRszA/Onls//nXXG/pXM077rmcxAAAAAAAAu7Lavnk2+/6p6cmrwKY/mqFPS/X5S6Bz5Zk6Z2foizNML1x3ywAAAAAAALuH2r55an5Exn5jqr+whDc7M/YFqen3190eAAAAAADArmdjv70y9K+kpiel+phlwuaSVF+SoU9KTc/KZt9x3W0CAAAAAADsQvqaGbZ/NsP0qNT06mUbtItTfe7yeGxq+psM2z+77k4BAAAAAAB2HTu298nQD8o4PyPVH0z1ztT05VSftQpq5rel5t/PsHX7dbcKAAAAAACwa7j+/t+fse+TcX5Canpzqs9O9ZdT06mpPitDfyHVL88w/a9sbt163e0CAAAAAABc/d2kr5dxvnPG6fdS/fJUf3rZ4uyUjH1qaro81R/IOD8jQ98/1Tdbd8sAAAAAAABXf5tbt071r6fmg1J93Gqbsz411Z9M9ZmpPj1Dvz41/XHG+S65SV9v3S0DAAAAAABcvW32D6bmrdT0pFQfmeoLUv2lVH9q2e7snFQfnuonpuatjAf80LpbBgAAAAAAuHrb8wFDarpran5yhj4i1V9J9fmpPiNDX5jq01N9WGr+mwzzgdnY+tF1twwAAAAAAPBdpP9b9nzAkB37fW82+wczbN0im/0TGbZ/OpvTnVJ9t4zTfVPbD0vNf5ian5yan52aX5HqozP2p1J9TqovX9V8doY+MTX/S4b5tzPOd8nGfnute5UAAAAAAADfwuO/Jze69/Uz9J7Z+4AbpbZ+ODu298m49ZPZ6DtknO+SYbpHxt4vw3RAxn5Ian5Exul3Uv1HGefHp/qJGeanp6ZnZegXpOZ/TvXBqT401e9M9TEZ+4RUn7ycHXN6qs9O9UVL0HJpqi9M9XlL+HL28nhexr4g1Zcsn3dRqs/K0J9fzp85IdXHp/qdGefHZEf/WHKP66z7HQUAAAAA4OpinPbNOO277jb4z9j3Wsk9rpMbPmiP7PmAIUPvmR37fW+uv//3Z88DfiB1/yX46P+R4YDbr6ZFtn4pm/M9M/Z+qd7OMP1aav6NDFu/lXF+zCoA6cel+q9S/ZSM89NT89+n5mdnnF+Yml6W6lem5oMz9htT/eZUfyBjn5jqo1J9bKqPy9AnLeHIKUtA8vnlDJevLOe3nL8KP6ZLU71zCUMuW4KRi5YzX85L9blLeHJWqs9M9RmrM2DmLy3XOz3VX1zq9OXjZ6f6vAx9UWq68roXLEHL6Us/J6fmE1LTMRn6Xanpzal+VWo+KDX9dcb+3Yzzg7Mx3SsbfYcMW7fI0Huu+38cAAAAAIBd0TC/KMN0aWo681tXn7eqf++5b6f6K99mnbHUOctN+2/4+Fevd9ZSZ69qvnIy4io1n5dhvjBDX5Lqo1N9yDJ5cehyo/6wpQ5PzYen+i1LvTXVb1vV9PbUdHzGPiFjvzurg+Tfm+pjUv3+1HTcMm1xUqo/kuqPpfoTS2Dx6VSfmrFPW4KLLyzhwpeX9VzZ/7nL+3rBcu7JRam+eAk1Ll2ChyvDjctTfcVSl3+T+saP71yucelVgpELl/DkymDkylDkS6n+wtLzZ5Z1fDzVH83QH8pqquT9y/t55BLYfDDVh2To16X6lal+acZ+QWo+KMP0d6npqan+q4zTn2WjH5thelRq+2HZnB+Y6imb870z9K9mmO6RYf7lVN8tNd0143yXjP0L2ZzulI3555cA5fYZtn861bfNuPWTGbdvk83+iWxs/Wiqb5br7//9GXrP3PBBeyR9zXX/qAEAAAAAwLc29OO+veDlyoCmz1zqrKs8d9Z/ss7+1jWdv6r57K/V1339VXqazl3CjkuWcOIbg4udGfq9GeajMvRRGfrIVU3vydDvXuqIpd61mr6Y35nqdyx1/BLOHJ5V6POvGfr1qX7NElK8PEO/NMP8otT8vNT07FT/Q8Z+5mpaZXpqqp+YcX7C6r2f/yTVj824/TsZ5t9K9cMzbj90FWLMczZ6v2xs3yu1ffeMB+ybzfnnM2z/dPbYvk12bO+T2r55xv1vmr36xtnjwBtmY7+9stm1CirucR1hBQAAAAAA8F/jJn291HT3jPOfp/pVqT5u2SLr0nztPJIvL8HKK1PTH2dj+rlViAEAAAAAAMC3b3P7VtnYenBqelrG6T1ZnYly+jI9c8VXg5nVYfIHZ+i/zLB9j2wcuPe6WwcAAAAAALh62Nhvr9TWL2WYH5Oan5PVmTEfWU3H9MVLKLMz1edn6NOW81PenbH/Mptb9zQxAwAAAAAA8C3d4zoZ+kcy7n+XDP3o1PSs1Hxoqk/I0F9I9QVXOV/m0uUsmk+sApnpJan+02xs3ys7HvS9614JAAAAAADAd6+9D7hRhq3bZ+j7p/qJqX5Nqt+XsU/L+NVA5tIllDkv1aem+tjl856SsR+Scb/bJA+57rqXAgAAAAAA8N3tBr0j43zn1PyHqellq9Bl/sISxlyy1M5Un5nqj662NpuenbEfnXHaN9U3Sx7/PeteBgAAAAAAwNXH5va9Un1Yqj+W6tOX82QuX0KZs1J9cqrfkrGfmXH+n9noO2TvA2607rYBAAAAAACuvjb22yvD9q9l7INT/dlVMDNdmurPZuh3ZZz/d8a+TzYO3HvdrQIAAAAAAOw6NvsnMs6PWW1f1mcs0zOXpPrDqemgbEx3WneLAAAAAAAAu5bxfmOG/pVsTH+9OoOmL1zq0lSfkGF+emrrdutuEwAAAAAAYNdTW7fL0I/LOJ24hDNnLdM0H0xNT8pm33HdLQIAAAAAAOx6btLXy9j7ZejXLQHNeanemWE6MdV/lZp/Kdn3WutuEwAAAAAAYNez0bdMzU9bnUPTV6T6slR/JjU/PxvTvXKD3rHuFgEAAAAAAHZNtf2wVL811Wcv2519JdWHZHN+YDYO3Hvd7QEAAAAAAOyiHv89qenVGfpzS0hzYarfl6Eflz33v8m6uwMAAAAAANi11byV6mOuMk3zpmxMP7futgAAAAAAAHZ9tfXDqX5uqs9M9eWpPiqb073W3RYAAAAAAMBu4OHXzrj14Ix9QqovTfUZGednZM8HDOvuDAAAAAAAYNdXfbPU/PxUX5Lqi1N9dDZM1QAAAAAAAHxnbG7dOtWHpnpnhr4wNT0rG9v/fd1tAQAAAAAA7B5qunuq379sgXZqxn50kmusuy0AAAAAAIDdw9CPTPWnUn15qo/JON9l3S0BAAAAAADsPob5Rak+N9UXZ+jXZu8DbrTulgAAAAAAAHYftXW7DP2RZRu0V6+7HQAAAAAAgN1PTU9L9aUZ+0STNQAAAAAAAN9pm1u3TvVHMvSFGeenr7sdAAAAAACA3U9NnWG+JNVnZXO+97rbAQAAAAAA2P2MW49J9QWpPsp2aAAAAAAAAOuwMf1eqi9Pzc9ZdysAAAAAAAC7r+qjU33SutsAAAAAAADYvVW/PdWfWHcbAAAAAAAAu7dx/r+pviJ5+LXX3QoAAAAAAMDua5zum+pzMmzdft2tAAAAAAAA7N6qz8nYJ2avvvG6WwEAAAAAANh9Df3IVJ+V6ksz9udS08syzPdcd1sAAAAAAAC7p+pfzNgvTvWnUr0z1Zel+tOpflM2DrjTutsDAAAAAADYPQ39KxmmQ1J96hLiXJyxT8wwPz07tvdZd3sAAAAAAAC7p2H7ARmnN6T6S6nemaEvTm09Yt1tAQAAAAAA7F72vs9GhvkvUv3hVF+xmryZ77futgAAAAAAAHZ9G/vtlbGfmZpPWYKaczL2G7PndPd1twYAAAAAALCru0aqX52hv7gKaqYvZpz/KbX9U+tuDAAAAAAAYNdXW3Oq35fqy1P95Qz9+mz2D667LQAAAAAAgN3DxvzzqT4j1Zdl6CNSfbd1twQAAAAAALD72aO/L2M/c91tAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPAf8P8Al8Ru+PcLKj0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=
```

Then using

```
$('#signature').jSignature("importData","data:image/png;base64,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")
```

works